# Calculating effect size for Jonckheere-Terpstra in R

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, effect-size, trend

I have used the JonckheereTersptraTest function in R and got a significant p-value. I would like to calculate effect size, but cannot figure out how to do this in R. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The only results provided by the function are JT = 159.5 and p-value = 0.005.

Comment: I haven't seen one, but the Jonckheere-Terpstra is equivalent to a test of Kendall's tau-b (but it seems there's some variation in implementation of tests for Kendall's tau-b, so it won't be perfectly equivalent to all of those implementations); this would suggest that perhaps one viable measure of effect size might be based off that connection. You might want to consider a more anova-like measure, but that would take some work to figure out exactly how to implement such a thing in a way that makes sense.